# Xamarin.forms' app name localization is not working

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/advanced/localization/
This document describes well.

But It's not working on iOS.
Even Sample Todoapp there is not showing localized app name.
It's just English.

How to use localized app name?

Comment: What have you tried and/or implemented? This will be by the department of open doors; but you did set your device to some other language right?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes. The sample app support Espanol. But It does not work even if I changed iPhone to Spanish.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis I'm sorry. It's working now. I might have mistaken somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app name fall out of the `Xamarin.Forms` realm, and should be localized using platform specific mechanisms

Comment: Yes I know. But it's not working. Even sample app is not working now.